# Where to ask questions about product design outside of electronics?

Tags: discussion

I couldn't make title short and to the point, just let me elaborate it:
What is the correct SE site where to ask questions like:

1. Case design(materials, airflow, geometry, standards, etc)
2. Licensing, certification of product
3. Manufacturing, shipping, logistics, etc
4. General questions about product design(EE company management, common non-electronics related practices in product design industry)

It would really be nice to have separate "Product design SE", but I suspect not many questions are out there for such thing.

But for example I am designing electronic device and I have question about casing, like what material can I use under high temperature or pressure(just an example). I guess EE is not the best place to ask this, but where to go then? Or maybe its OK here?

Have to say I actually don't have any questions like this at the moment, but I am just curious where can I go if I will have something like this to ask.

Comment: Maybe google? There are also a few other SE sites that would be good also.

Comment: It may be time to consider hiring a CTO.  [Sorry, I couldn't resist.]

Comment: @laptop2d, what SE sites would you suggest that allow(or better yet encourage) such questions?

Comment: Would the Engineering.SE beta work?

Comment: EMC concerns when designing a case is perfectly on-topic. It is hard to design an electronics case without considering EMC at some degree. Similarly, questions regarding "chassis ground", where/how to connect shields, antenna concerns etc etc are on-topic. As are questions about IP class, when it comes to isolating a high voltage device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is related to electronic design, ask here.  Things like mechanical and thermal issues of case design are on topic at engineering.SE.  Some of the company management *might* be on topic at workplace.SE.  Much of the shipping and logistics is probably not on topic anywhere here.

There are new SE sites popping up all the time.  The best thing to do is go thru the list to see what's available.  That's better than us guessing about those we happen to know about.  Put another way, you need to do your own homework.